# How to stop my xml file duplicating on refresh but renewing instead?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this xml file which has text init.

i.e

**Hi my name is steven**

When i add a **Setinterval** to load the xml file every 10 seconds i get

**Hi my name is stevenHi my name is stevenHi my name is stevenHi my name is steven**
This continues duplicating every 10 seconds

Here is my javascript xml function

```
myLoadInteval = setInterval(Xml, 10000);

function Xml(){ 

$(document).ready(function() {  
                  $.ajax({  
                         type: "GET",  
                         url: "http://www.mobilefriendlywebapps.co.uk/tayloredtest1/note.xml",  
                         dataType: "xml",  
                         success: parseXml  
                         });  
                  function parseXml(xml) {  
                  $(xml).find("menu").each(function() {  
                                           //find each instance of loc in xml file and wrap it in a link 
                                           $("div#site_list").append( $(this).find("cd").text() );  
                                           $("div#treatments").append( $(this).find("cd1").text() ); 
                                           $("div#preparation").append( $(this).find("cd2").text() );
                                           $("div#products").append( $(this).find("cd3").text() );
                                           $("div#info").append( $(this).find("cd4").text() );
                                           $("div#price").append( $(this).find("cd5").text() );
                                           $("div#promo").append( $(this).find("cd6").text() );
                                           });  
                  }  

                  });
```

}

How do i remove the old xml before the new on loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using append() use html()

i.e

```
$("div#site_list").html( $(this).find("cd").text() );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood right, you're getting duplicate content because you're appending to the HTML elements each time, not emptying them first. If you want to replace the contents, do just that, rather than appending. So:

```
$("div#site_list").append( $(this).find("cd").text() );
```

...would become

```
$("div#site_list").text($(this).find("cd").text());
```

Or, if you XML contains CData-protected HTML mark-up, use the `html()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks your explanation helped me understand the differences ,